# Indexing foreign key in doctrine 2 to optimize query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

**Consultant Entity**

```
<?php        
        namespace Entity;
        /**
         * @Entity
         * @Table(name="consultant")
         */
        class Consultant{    

          /**
           * @Id
           * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
           * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
           */
          protected $id;
          /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
      }
```

**Paitent Entity**

```
      <?php

        namespace Entity;
        /**
         * @Entity
         * @Table(name="patient")
         */
        class Patient{


          /**
           * @Id
           * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
           * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
           */
          protected $id;
          /**
      * Many Patients belogns to a single consultant.
      * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="consultant")
      * @JoinColumn(name="consultant_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
      */
      private $consultant;
      /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Set consultant
     *
     * @param \Entity\consultant $consultant
     *
     * @return Patient
     */
    public function setConsultant(\Entity\consultant $consultant)
    {
        $this->consultant = $consultant;
        $consultant->addPatient($this);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get consultant
     *
     * @return \Entity\consultant
     */
    public function getConsultant()
    {
        return $this->consultant;
    }
 }
```

**Query Builder**

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
      $qb
        ->select('p')
        ->from('Entity\Consultant', 'c')
        ->innerJoin('Entity\Patient', 'p', 'c.id = p.consultant_id')
        ->where('c.id = ?1')               
        ->setParameter(1, 1)        
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $results = $query->getResult();
```

**Question**

I need to get all the patients which belongs to a particular consultant and i'm currently using the above query builder query in doctrine 2. To optimize the above query do i have to index consultant_id in the patient entity? If yes how to do it in doctrine 2? And also any other optimizing techniques are also welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine automatically creates an index on the foreign key field so no need to try to add one manually. Also to get all the patients which belongs to a consultant a join is not necessary as shown in the question but a simpler query could be used which is mentioned below.

**New Query**

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
       $qb
          ->select('p.name')
          ->from('Entity\Patient', 'p')        
          ->where('p.consultant = ?1')
          ->setParameter(1, 1);
```